# Does a non-grounded disc, near a charged disc, behave like one side of a parallel plate capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, capacitance

I’m using a new FEA software and I’m getting an unexpected result.

This is a simplified diagram of my simulation problem. I expect that a disc charged with one volt would have a capacitance similar to C = (8 e R) even though a non-grounded disc is near by. However, the software provides a capacitance as if the second disc was grounded, thus as if it were a parallel plate capacitor. The diagram is colored to show the electrostatic induction in the non-grounded disc.

Am I wrong in assuming the capacitance of the single disc, in the presence of a non-grounded disc, should be closer to that of a single disc rather than that of a parallel plate capacitor?

[image: Diagram of conducting discs.]

Comment: The disc formula assumes that there are no objects nearby. [Field of a Charged Conducting Disc](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/Elec_Mag/2022_Lectures/EM_23_ChargedConductingDisc.html)

Comment: Following Farcher’s lead I found this digital text book, which provides a clear example of how the disc assumes that there are no objects nearby. However, in my link the author uses a charge within a conductive sphere. Thank you Farcher.

https://peppyhare.github.io/r/notes/griffiths/ch2-5/